# Insert if multiple rows don't exist, update if they do

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-update

I have a table that looks similar to this...

```
+-------------+-------------+
| Field       | Type        |
+-------------+-------------+
| var1        | varchar(15) |
| var2        | varchar(25) |
| var3        | int(1)      |
+-------------+-------------+
```

The issue is that I need to be able to insert the 3 variables, but only if var1 and var2 aren't already in the table. If var1 and var2 are already in the table, var3 should be updated.

So for example

```
INSERT INTO table (var1, var2, var3) VALUES('0','1','2')
```

Would insert the 3 values, but

```
INSERT INTO table (var1, var2, var3) VALUES('0','1','1')
```

Would update ('0','1','2') to be ('0','1','1')

The important thing is that if var1 and var2 exist, a duplicate entry with a different var3 is not entered.

I've looked around at a few other questions, but most of them seem to recommend IGNORE which I don't think will work for me since I'm checking for multiple duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set `(var1,var2)` as combined `PRIMARY KEY`

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY(var1,var2)
```

Then use [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (var1, var2, var3) VALUES ('0','1','2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE var3 = '2'
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't realize you could have multiple primary keys. Also, I had to remove the "SET" after "UPDATE" for it to work.